# What to do with old boxing gloves?

Tags: exercise-equipment, boxing

I've been boxing for about 100 sessions. I am now on my third pair of gloves.

My first pair is generally pretty good. Inside, there is a thin liner and foam under the liner. The liner tore after about 70 sessions, and the gloves started shedding little pieces of white foam. The outside of the glove is completely fine, but when my hand comes out of the glove it's covered in pieces of white foam, and the foam somehow seems to get ejected when I'm punching. I'm not sure how it gets out, because there's no tears on the outside, and it's usually strapped pretty tight on my hand. Anyways, I can't really wear it because I don't want the gym to get mad that I'm making a mess, and yet I feel bad throwing away a glove that seems otherwise to be functional.

My second pair was less robust and started getting tears on the plastic coating outside after 30 sessions. I didn't like the feel of this pair anyway, so I jumped on the excuse to buy a new pair.

The third pair I just got is much nicer, since I decided to pay a bit more for it, and I really hope it lasts more than a year or two. However now I still have to figure out what to do with the other two.

What do you do with your old gloves, that are mostly usable, but you're probably not ever going to use them? I imagine most people will balk at used boxing gloves, even if free. Should I just stop worrying and toss them in the bin?

Comment: Toss or donate. Worrying won't help. :) It's nice you don't want to make a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options for you:

- Donate to a beginner one who cannot afford
- Sell via classified websites or trade
- If their is any issue, repair them and use it